# Datamapper not saving records to MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby, sinatra, datamapper, amazon-rds

Datamapper isn't saving my user models.
(This is a Sinatra webapp and the db is an AWS RDS mysql db.)

The User model:

```
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :uid, Serial
  property :user, String, :key => true, :length => 3..20
  property :pass, String, :required => true, :length => 6..50
end
```

The code to set it:

```
post "/register" do
  username = params["username"]
  password = params["password"]
  begin
    encrypted_password = BCrypt::Password.create password
    meme = User.new :user => username, :pass => encrypted_password
    meme.save
    raise DatabaseError, "User record not saved" unless meme.saved?
    flash[:register] = "Welcome, new user! Please log in now."
    redirect "/login"
  # disabled rescue stuff...
  end
end
```

(if you want, test it yourself at [dittoslash.uk](http://dittoslash.uk/register))
(can i do this on stack overflow? edit this out if you can't)

**EDIT:** Updated validation rules. Now I'm getting an error of 'Pass must be between 6 and 50 characters long' (with a 28 (or 30?) character password)

Comment: You have set up database error to raise if the meme does not save. Check the validation errors on the record. And please post an original error as text in your question.

Comment: I can't post an original error, because this dosen't normally raise an error.

Comment: 'pass must be at most 50 characters long'
.e.

Comment: updated with new error

Comment: You don't show your validation definitions though. This length requirement has to come from somewhere

Comment: `property :pass, String, :required => true, :length => 6..50` e.e

Comment: Sorry I didn't see that at first. Check the length of `encrypted_password`. You may have to do something like `BCrypt::Password.create(password).first(50)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

max pleaner answered this for me.

For Googlers looking for answers:
check your validations, and make sure that encryption dosen't make the password longer than your maximum.